# How to order by model property value?

Tags: python, django

How to order by model property?

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    check_permission = models.BooleanField()
    remove_permission = models.BooleanField()
    ...
    
    @property
    def permissions_count(self) -> int:
        count = 0
        if self.check_permission:
            count += 1
        if self.remove_permission:
            count += 1
        return count


qs = Item.objects.all()
if order_by == 'permissions_count':
    qs = qs.order_by('permissions_count')
return qs
```

I see this error:

**Cannot resolve keyword 'permissions_count' into field. Choices are:**

Comment: You can not order on a property, since the database does not know anything about properties. These are functions that are defined in Python. You can try to convert it to an annotation, but that of course requires to know the logic in the `permissions_count`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the suggestion. I just updated permissions_count method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `Item`s and then order by that number:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F

qs = Item.objects.annotate(
    num_permissions=(
        Cast('check_permission', output_field=IntegerField()) +
        Cast('remove_permission', output_field=IntegerField())
    )
).order_by('num_permissions')
```

Comment: Thanks, I see this error now: operator does not exist: boolean + boolean HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @user3115655: ah yes, some databases require to cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) to annotate the values in the queryset, then order by it. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntergerField, Value, Q

Item.objects.annotate(permission_count=Case(
     When(Q(check_permission=True)&Q(remove_permission=True), then=Value(2)),
     When(Q(check_permission=True)|Q(remove_permission=True), then=Value(1)),
     default=Value(0),
     output_field=IntergerField())
).order_by('permission_count')
```

Comment: Looks good, but let's assume that I have more than 30 permission so the code will be very long.